# get return from another power shell script

Tags: powershell

I have a PS script which `Invoke-Expression` on other scripts on the same computer.
Here is the code:

```
$webMemory = "C:\Memory_Script\WebMemory_Script.ps1"
$intMemory = "C:\Memory_Script\IntMemory_Script.ps1"
$hungWeb = "C:\Scripts\HungWeb_Script.ps1"
$hungInt = "C:\Scripts\HungInt_Script.ps1"

$intMemoryResult = @()
$webMemoryResult = @()
$hungWebResult = @()
$hungIntResult = @()

$date = Get-Date
$shortDate =  (get-date -format ddMMyyy.hhmm)
$filepath = "C:\Scripts\Memory&HungResults\Results" + $shortdate + ".txt"
$break = "`r`n"

out-file -filepath $filepath -inputobject $date -force -encoding ASCII -width 50
out-file -filepath $filepath -Append -inputobject $break -encoding ASCII -width 50

$intMemoryResult += Invoke-Expression $intMemory
$webMemoryResult += Invoke-Expression $webMemory
$hungWebResult += Invoke-Expression $hungWeb
$hungIntResult += Invoke-Expression $hungInt

Write-host $webMemoryResult

out-file -filepath -Append -inputobject $intMemoryResult -encoding ASCII -width 200
out-file -filepath -Append -inputobject $break -encoding ASCII -width 200
out-file -filepath -Append -inputobject $webMemoryResult -encoding ASCII -width 200
out-file -filepath -Append -inputobject $break -encoding ASCII -width 200
out-file -filepath -Append -inputobject $hungIntResult -encoding ASCII -width 200
out-file -filepath -Append -inputobject $break -encoding ASCII -width 200
out-file -filepath -Append -inputobject $hungWebResult -encoding ASCII -width 200
out-file -filepath -Append -inputobject $break -encoding ASCII -width 200
```

Code in one of the scripts being called (the other three have similar functions)

```
$serverList = @("List of servers")

$w3wpMemory = @()
$w3wpMemory += "---------- W3WP Memory Consumption ----------"
$w3wpresult = @()
$toBeRecycled =@()
$toBeRecycled += "******************** THE INT SERVERS BELOW NEED TO BE RECYCLED (Hung) ********************" + "`r`n"

$date = Get-Date
$shortDate =  (get-date -format ddMMyyy.hhmm)
$filepath = "C:\Scripts\HungIntResults\HungServerResults" + $shortdate + ".txt"
$break = "`r`n"

out-file -filepath $filepath -inputobject $date -force -encoding ASCII -width 50
out-file -filepath $filepath -Append -inputobject $break -encoding ASCII -width 50

ForEach($server in $serverList)
{
    $w3wpresult += (get-wmiobject Win32_Process -filter "commandline like '%serviceoptimization%'" -computername $server).privatepagecount / 1gb
$w3wpMemory += $server + ":" + $w3wpresult + "`n" 
}    

$i = 0
ForEach($server in $serverList)
{
    $w3wpresult2 = (get-wmiobject Win32_Process -filter "commandline like '%serviceoptimization%'" -computername $server).privatepagecount / 1gb

    Write-Host $w3wpresult2 " , " ($w3wpresult | select-object -index $i) 

    if($w3wpresult -contains ($w3wpresult2))
    {
        $toBeRecycled += $server + "`r`n"
    }
    $i = $i + 1
}


$toBeRecycled += "*******************************************************************************"
$toBeRecycled += "`r`n"
Write-Host $toBeRecycled

out-file -filepath $filepath -Append -inputobject $toBeRecycled -encoding ASCII -width 100

return $toBeRecycled
```

When the script runs, I see the output of from the execution of the other scripts.
The results from the "Invoke-Expression" command are returning null, why is this?

Comment: Why do you use `Invoke-Expression` to call the scripts?

Comment: I'm getting a result from a test.ps1 using `Invoke-Expression`, if you run the script by itself does it generate the expected output? Also you could try `Write-Host ($hungWebResult | Out-String)` to see whats in the array before you call `out-file`.

Comment: I use `Invoke-Expression` since i need to wait for each script to complete before executing another.

When i run each script separately, they all function as intended.

When calling `Write-Host`, it returns null.

Comment: @StephenSugumar This is close to impossible to diagnose without seeing the contents of one of the script files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Write-Host` writes directly to the host display.  If you want to capture this output then use `Write-Output` instead or just put a variable on a line by itself because the default output is the "output" stream:

```
$toBeRecycled
```

BTW when you execute a PowerShell script from another PowerShell script, the child script will execute synchronously (unless you are using jobs).

Comment: Thank you for the reply,
I removed the `return` from the for scripts.

`write-output $intMemoryResult` still yields null
and nothing gets written into the output file

Comment: Which output file?  You're writing to an output file in the child script as well as the parent script.  Are they all empty?  Also this bit in your parent script is not right `out-file -filepath -append` - you have not specified any filename. That should cause an error.

Comment: Thanks, It was the error in the `out-file` which was messing everything up.

Nonetheless, i learned from your answer!